# Remove Letters in the End of the Words

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Goal:
To remove the letters in the end of every word.
I would like to achieve the result from the column "Requested result".

Problem:
How do I do it by using VBA coding?
Don't forget the "white space".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Excel formula**

```
=MID(A2,1,SEARCH("(",A2,1)-1)
```

[image]

**Using VBA**

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(i, 2) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 1, InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "(", vbTextCompare) - 1)
    Next
End Sub
```